# Что выбрать для создания графических приложений на python?

Tags: python

Подскажите, какую выбрать графическую библиотеку для создания приложений. Так, чтобы можно было бы делать крутые и красивые интерфейсы, не знаю, что выбрать.
Желательно выскажите пару аргументов в пользу той или иной графической библиотеки. Важные критерии - возможность создавать,крутые, современные и красивые интерфейсы, 'развивающаяся' библиотека.

Comment: `PyQt` - реализация фреймворка Qt для языка Python.

    `pip install PyQt5`  
    `pip install pyqt5-tools`

Comment: «крутые, современные и красивые» — чересчур субъективная характеристика. Для кого-то и Tkinter красивый.

Comment: pyqt5 9 символов нужно...

Answer (score 1):

Qt-QML декларативный интерфейс с кучей эффектов, анимашек и хорошей отзывчивостью. Подключается через pyside2 или pyqt5.

Часто также делают интерфейсы на html  и заворачивают в web-view.

Для нативных интерфесов хорошо идет gtk3 и qt5. Gtk3 подключается через gi.